# Dispatcher didn't mention me in Jira task; how should I clarify?

Tags: communication, team, task-management

I work in an IT department with Jira. Before the ticket reaches my team, a dispatcher has to delegate the Jira-Task to someone.

**The "problem "** : it appears more than once (today will be the tenth time less in one month), that the dispatcher (it is only one person) mentions all team members except me.

**My question**: should I clarify with him, why he does not mention me, and if so, how should I phrase it?

My thoughts were something like : *"Hey [name of dispatcher], it seems that when the tickets come in you mention all the team members, why?"*

Comment: Yep, seems like a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I preferred to wait and see if things would get better.

Comment: @Warok, I'm not following what is the problem here. How does the "dispatcher" not mention you? Do they list all the members in the ticket description? In the "Assignee" field? Nevertheless, it seems to me, the workflow you're following is a bit skewed. The reporter (dispatcher) should not normally assign the tickets.

Comment: What does "mention" mean? Is this so you can see the ticket? If true, this is such a stupid process that lends itself to these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps those tickets are not for you? And thus why you are not getting them?

Anyways, it would be ok to ask for clarification in a polite and professional way to the Dispatcher. A phrasing I can think of is (working a bit from your thoughts):

> Hey [name of dispatcher], I've noticed that you mentioned all the team members on this last ticket, except me. I'm writing to let you know in case I am supposed to be mentioned also, or, on the contrary case, so you can clarify why this task is not for me.
>
> Thanks, Warok

Comment: These tickets could be for me, I have the same level as my team members. Sorry to mention it, but thanks for the wording

Answer (score 0):

> "Should I be included in these emails? I want to make sure I don't
> miss something. Thanks."